# Is there a comment history?

Tags: discussion, comments

Visiting an [old question](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/221/266) which came up as related for a new one (Tschau/Tschüß/Servus/Grüß Gott), I found an answer, which I thought I have commented before. But I'm not sure.

Since there are occasionally comment-clean-ups, I can imagine it was removed without notice. Now I rewrite the same comment I did before?

I guess there is no possibility for our moderators to verify, that there was a comment which now is removed? That means I might add the same commment and it might get removed in 6 or 12 months from now again, then being added by me in the same spirit as before, producing work for both of us, again and again reanimating an old discussion without progress.

It proves my point from the [clean up discussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/445/266) here:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was repeatedly pointed out and outlned again in my answer to the following post

- [Why should I edit or answer rather than comment?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/why-should-i-edit-or-answer-rather-than-comment)

comments are on all StackExchage sites **not meant to answer** but they are an additional tool given to users having gained the [privilege to comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) to ask for clarification or add additional information to any post.

These comments are meant to be **temporary** notes. Ideally they should lead to an edit of a post to include information from comments or improve a post according to suggestions made. Comments may also be used to give users a short feedback why we downvoted to give tham a chance for improvements.

**In any case:** once an issue was resolved or comments were read they should be deleted for cleaning up the posts. This is one of those cumbersome janitorial tasks for moderators which eats up our time. That is why we asked for help by **deleting own comments** after an issue was resolved, and by **flagging obsolete comments**. I am glad that many users follow this. Still, there are many posts in need of clean-up.

We should not expect moderators to read through all comments in a lengthy comment thread (we are talking about 10+ comments) to find possibly hidden valuable information in a single comment in case the whole thread became obsolete or was off-topic for that given post. These comments will definitely go with the whole comment thread on clean-up.

Whenever we want to add **valuable information** that should stay we should do so in an **answer** or an **edit**, not in a comment.

Moderators only can view all flags, comments, or edits, including deleted comments in a post's history:

[image]

This also give moderators a tool to undelete accidentally deleted comments:

[image]

We can not however undelete an own-deleted comment from any user.

Before we flag a post for moderator attention to undelete any deleted comment of ours we should think twice if this comment really was within the range defined for comments, or if an additional answer or an edit to a post was a better alternative. Whenever there will be a comment delete/undelete war moderators will not hesitate to lock a post to prevent this, or in extreme cases temporarily suspend a user who abuses the comment system in order to protect the site.

Whenever a user flags a comment for deletion we usually will happily do so in case the flag was correct. This is even more so if it was a rude/offensive flag. In the latter case we will mostly delete this comment but if we disagreed with the comment being rude we may first dismiss the flag to delete this comment later. It would not help the site much if we let a comment stay when somebody else felt offended by it.

---

For the [post in question](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/221/266) we can not see any deleted comments in the post's history.

Comment: Your insistence on rules corresponds well to the lack of content on this beta site. On well-working SE sites this attitude is not the norm. But already your first sentence of this answer shows that you are not willing to have an open conversation about it.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: come on, it is the [network wide Stack Exchange **default** guide on commenting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) we follow here, nothing special about German Language. Complaints about this should go to http://meta.stackexchange.com/.